# Primefaces fileUpload it isn't rendered as it should

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.0.M4-Snapshot and I'm trying to integrate the new fileUpload component: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf (it looks nicer like a toolbar), but when I run the page the fileUpload looks exactly like the old one: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf...
I'm using the latest namespace: `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`
This is my primefaces code:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"
                                        update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

</h:form>
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have the Primefaces 3.0.M4 library in your classpath?

Comment: If I wouldn't have 3.0.M4, the latest namespace `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` would not work

Comment: PrimeFaces logs version information on startup, can you double check?.

Comment: How do you see the log? Firebug?

Comment: Wait a minute, Firebug logs that there is a connection error: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8090/CreazioneV49/images/themes/"`... CreazioneV49 is my project name but why is it searching for that folder: images/themes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I have resolved the problem: I'm using Netbeans 7 which integrates Primefaces 2.2.1, the library that I have been using from the begging of my project... It seems that the library Primefaces 2.2.1 was still in the Ant-Deploy. After a rename, a clean project and a deploy, my project works great!
Thank you all!